# Jquery not selector for multiple class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jquery not selector. what I want is to select the 'content' class that does not have a button class in it and then select span tag. I tried the below code but it did not work:

```
$(".content:not('.button') span");
```

Comment: is `span` inside `.content`?

Comment: It would really help if you could provide some sample HTML.

Comment: yes, span is inside .content

Comment: It is maybe a bit overcomplicated. The code will be much nicer if you just .each the contents, or even better, add some classes to them to them and make selections from that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
$(".content:not(:has('.button')) span");
```

Or:

```
$('.content').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).find('.button').length;
}).find('span');
```

Comment: Seeing a selector or logic like that in my code would really make me think about the structure of my HTML or how I'm analyzing it.

Comment: Me too, but without any information as to the HTML's structure (I see you already requested that), or information on what the OP's trying to do, it's the best I can offer at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Use `:not(:has(selector))`, here's a working example:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/NDJb8/)

```
$(".content:not(:has(.button)) span");
```